# excel vba read whole text file at once

Tags: macros, basic, quickbasic

I am using CADCAM Software and writing macro code. Here is my basic macro code.

```
OPEN "C:\Area ratio\etch.txt" FOR INPUT as #1
DO WHILE NOT EOF (1) =1
    LINE INPUT #1, REC$
    if REC$="" then goto jump2
    'PRINT REC$
    y2#=Y2#-200
    Addtext@ x2#,y2#,0,0,REC$
jump2:
LOOP
CLOSE #1
Clearmarkers@
end@
```

This code will be working fine. but it will read the text and print line by line.

I need to print read whole text file at once.

Answer (score 7):

```
Sub Test()

    'Tools -> References -> Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim txt As TextStream
    Dim all_text As String

    Set txt = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\Temp\textfile.txt")
    all_text = txt.ReadAll
    txt.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: hi, @JohnyL I am sorry your code 100% working fine in excel VBA. but here I using the basic macro. I put them your code but it will show syntax errors. I need to macro code

Comment: @YowE3K Comment deleted! :) I was really confused until I watched editions. Watching changes is useful and cool thing! :) Happy New Year! :)